# Cropping images in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap columns. My images have different sizes.

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
<div class="col-lg-12" >
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <img src="imgpath1" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="imgpath2" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3">
    <img src="imgpath3" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

css:

```
.row.no-gutter {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

How it looks now:[image]
How it should be:[image]

You can see (in ideal solution) that images weren't resized, but cropped by center.

I've tried many things so far, but any solution solved it. Many solutions don't kept the responsive behavior.

Comment: Your markup doesn't match with your css shown here, make a jsfiddle.net please

Comment: My fault, I've edited!. About the fiddle, I tried, but it seems not representing as well the problem I have

Comment: @Godinall, any thoughts? :)

Comment: 1. use calc() to dynamically set width and height, not recommended; 2. use background image for col-lg-3 instead of img tag; 3. use jquery

Comment: It's a bit late now if you try above options and I will have a look tomorrow.

Comment: By using your opt2. How would it be about responsive ?

Comment: Your html needs a bit of work. Look at the docs on nested grids: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change images from html to css so it is background image.
Then set it to background-size:cover;
Note that this works only in IE9 and later.